# Tool to convert T-SQL to graphical model?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sometimes I am looking at complex SQL Server SQL statements and wondered if there's a tool which can represent the query into a graphical model.

For example:

You have a select query which joins (could be inner + left and right joins) with 10 tables. Is there a tool to take this query, represent the 10 tables graphically and draw the different joins as relationships? And better yet, if you modify the joins and conditions graphically, it automatically updates the generated sql.

Think of it like a reverse query builder. You start from the sql query and end at the model.

Comment: will any of these answers work for queries with unions, derived tables, CTEs, and/or subqueries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Query Designer in Management Console is actually two-way.  You can use it to draw your query graphically, or you can paste or type in your t-sql and it will show a graphic display.

Just open a query window, then hit Ctrl-Shift-Q or choose "Design Query in Editor" from the Query menu.

Comment: Nice feature, did not know it.. horrible code it generates though :-)

Comment: I use SSMS a lot and didn't know it existed! I tried it and the thing always crashes even with the simplest queries when I start with the query. I see it starting to draw the tables and then the window disappears. I am using SSMS 2008 with SP1.

Comment: Actually I had an error and it works now. Although the designer should catch any errors and not bomb like that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a perfect solution but you can always view the [query execution plan](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/query_execution_plan_analysis_p1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Though not exactly what you are asking for, the TSQL Script Explorer from ISpySQL.com will come close. Disclaimer, I'm part of ISpySQL.com. Rob Vallee

Answer (score 0):

I will not be able to give you one single answer, as 'ultimate' is not a precise quality for a software since it will depend on your specific requirements, eg. : Is it for design or for documentation? do you want graph-2-sql round trip? or graph-2-your-dev-language? do you want to pay? which platform, which database? etc. 'Style' will also matter, as you might prefer complex and powerful tools or rather simple but quick ones.

so I'll give you a few pointers and I'll let you check out which one might better suit your needs, I hope it helps; there are probably several other tools I've forgotten or I do not know. Mind you, I've not tried them all, and I am currently mostly developing on django so I often sketch (yes, me too) on paper then directly write code.

If you want to 'draw' a database as a graph, and don't need to sync it with sql or code:

- Graph tools: [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) I really like the interface of this one for quick graphs drawings
- any UML tool, eg: [Poseidon](http://www.gentleware.com/), [Argo UML](http://argouml.tigris.org/), [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/solution/freeumltool), [Altova UML](http://www.altova.com/umodel.html), [MagicDraw](http://www.magicdraw.com/what_is), [IBM Rational Software Architect](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/products/rsa/), ...
- online tools: [ondra zara](http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/)

Many softwares allow you to directly edit a database model graphically, eg:

- [Sql Manager](http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/postgresql/manager/screenshots/1601)
- [Squirrel SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=screenshots)
- [PostgreSQL Designer](http://www.microolap.com/products/database/postgresql-designer/)
- [Druid](http://druid.sourceforge.net)
- [Erwin](http://erwin.com/products/detail/ca_erwin_data_modeler/)

If you just want to document 'existing' databases you'll have several options, eg.:

- python/django: [GraphModels](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/wiki/GraphModels)
- perl: [SQL:Translator](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SQL%3A%3ATranslator)