# Convert SQL query to graphic model

Tags: sql, model

I am taking up a question that was asked in 2009 and I would like to have an answer.

I am looking at complex SQL statements and wondered if there's a free tool (online, python library...) which can represent the query into a graphical model.

For example:

You have a select query which joins (could be inner + left and right joins) with 10 tables. Is there a tool to take this query, represent the 10 tables graphically and draw the different joins as relationships? And better yet, if you modify the joins and conditions graphically, it automatically updates the generated sql.

Think of it like a reverse query builder. You start from the sql query and end at the model.

Thank's !

Comment: Ask here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe the execution plan of the query can be of help. Not exactly what you want but it's available on most databases (text or graphic mode).

Comment: similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982917/tool-to-convert-t-sql-to-graphical-model